# Como rotar 180 grados horizontalmente un div

Tags: javascript, html, css3

tengo un simple ejemplo de un div, el cual quiero rotarlo 180 grados Horizontalmente, mi ejemplo gira verticalmente lo cual no quiero

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(27deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(37deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(37deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Hello</div>
<br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MarcosGallardo pero no se como hacer la transicion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Efecto: **Vuelta carta**

- Propiedad [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/perspective):

> Determina la distancia entre el plano z=0
>   y el usuario para dar algo de perspectiva al elemento 3D posicionado.

- Propiedad [transform-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) con el valor [preserve-3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style#Values):

> Indica que los hijos del elemento deben colocarse en el espacio 3D.

- Propiedad [backface-visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility):

> Determina si la superficie trasera de un elemento es visible cuando se
>   enfrenta el usuario. En este caso esta en
>   [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility#Values)
>   lo que significa que la superficie trasera no es visible.

- Propiedad [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

> Te permite modificar el espacio de coordenadas del modelo de formato
>   visual y con el valor
>   [rotateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY)
>   se mueve sobre el eje `Y`

---

```css
.carta-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carta-box:hover .carta {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.carta {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.cara {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cara.detras {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="carta-box">
  <div class="carta">    
    <div class="cara">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/250/tech" width="200" height="250px">
    </div>
    <div class="cara detras">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/250/animals" width="200" height="250px">
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes explicar tu codigo?

Answer (score 2):

Agrega lo siguiente a tu CSS. Existe otras formas de hacer como con librerías JQuery, pero no hace falta. Solo con CSS puro podes hacerlo.

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```