# Como usar rotateY y mostrar info por detras del elemento rotado

Tags: html5, css3

la idea es rotar una div sobre su eje Y y que al girar se visualice información en lo que seria la parte posterior de la caja (como si girara una tarjeta y viera el texto que tiene por detrás. Es esto posible? porque he visto varios ejemplos pero solo lo rotan sin mostrar nada por detrás (no se como agregar esto), lo mas cercano que llegue fue formar un cubo y que se muestre la cara lateral al rotar. Pero no me convenció porque tiene muchas fallas en algunos navegadores que no soportan el efecto.
Alguna idea de como lograrlo?

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40816/6491) tienes la respuesta...

Comment: no habia logrado encontrarla. muchas gracias!