# Invertir un div con css

Tags: css3, div, css-transform

Tengo esa flecha negra y la quiero trasladar y rotar al tiempo para que quede como la roja:

[image: ejemplo]

Habia visto que se podia con una sola propiedad pero me toco mientras asi:

```
transform-origin:bottom;
transform:rotateX(180deg)
```

Creo que era con translate3d pero no me sirvio.

Comment: Agrega el intento que haz realizado, HTML y CSS para poder ayudarte.

Comment: el texto en negrilla es el codigo en css, busco una forma mas simplificada

Comment: Verifica si [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40807/como-rotar-180-grados-horizontalmente-un-div) te funciona. ;)

Comment: 2 líneas de css es demasiado complejo ???

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example]

Comment: Obvio no es complejo esas 2 lineas pero queria saber si se puede hacer con una sola propiedad

Comment: En una sola instrucción me parece que no se puede, porque hasta donde yo se, no hay forma de cambiar el `origen` que está al centro de la imagen (que sería una 2da instrucción). Lo más cercano que se me ocurre es `transform:matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 100)`, siendo el 100 el height de la imagen, es decir tienes que conocerla de antemano